# Ansible via bastion box set UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null on bastion box

Tags: ssh, ansible

I've had very nondescript errors while trying to run ansible via a bastion host. I just figured out that if I connect to the bastion box and then inidividually ssh to the private ips adding the ips to the known_hosts on the bastion box then exiting and rerunning, ansible will work.

It seems the problem is that the private ips I try to get ansible to connect to via the bastion box aren't in the known_hosts file of the bastion box and I don't get a prompt to add them while running the playbook.

My ssh.cfg looks like this:

```
Host 172.*.*.*
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -A ubuntu@nat.cloudapp.net
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host nat.cloudapp.net
  Hostname nat.cloudapp.net
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ForwardAgent yes
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 5m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to test the .cfg file with ssh -F ssh.cfg user@172.16.0.5, that will tell you if your ssh.cfg file is working independent of ansible.

In my .cfg file, I list each host, because the wildcard on class C boundaries doesn't help me much.  Here is what a piece of mine looks like:

```
Host 10.0.0.4
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  Hostname 10.0.0.4
  User corona
  ForwardAgent yes
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 5m

Host 10.84.96.33
  ProxyCommand ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p corona@10.0.0.4
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
Host 10.84.96.36
  ProxyCommand ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p corona@10.0.0.4
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

It does seem weird, but I list the StringHostKeyChecking=no both on the proxycommand line and in the Host declaration.  Give that a try.

Comment: I tried it with `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p -A ubuntu@nat.cloudapp.net` and in the host declaration as above as well after deleting the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on the nat box but it didn't work.